# mysql Slow query to get post and tags

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have three tables. one that holds posts (`postadata`), one that holds tags(`tag`) and one linking table (`tag_data`)
I am running a query to get all the posts and their tags concatenated using the query below.

```
    SELECT 
        postdata.data_id as data_id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tag.tag_id)) as tag_ids, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tag.tag) ORDER BY tag.tag ASC) as tags
    FROM postdata
    LEFT JOIN tag_data as tag_data
            INNER JOIN tag as tag
                ON tag_data.tag_id = tag.tag_id
    ON postdata.data_id = tag_Data.data_id
    GROUP BY postdata.data_id
    LIMIT 1000
```

But it is very very slow. (around 20 seconds). Below is the explain, I can't seem to find the problem

```
1   SIMPLE  postdata    index   NULL    source_id   4   NULL            158808  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  tag_data    index   PRIMARY PRIMARY     8   NULL            45279   Using index
1   SIMPLE  tag         eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY     4   tag_data.tag_id 1
```

Below are the postdata indexes

```
postdata    0   PRIMARY     1   data_id     A   120405  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
postdata    1   source_id   1   source_id   A   168     NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Is it a problem with the query? is there a way to write it more efficiently?
Or is it a missing index?

**UPDATE:** Adding index info as per jordeu's comments

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM [database_name] WHERE Name='postdata'

```
Name        Engine  Version Row_format  Rows    Avg_row_length  Data_length Max_data_length Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time Update_time Check_time  Collation   Checksum    Create_options  Comment
postdata    InnoDB  10      Compact     158645  43              6832128     0               8421376         4194304     NULL            2012-03-08 09:22:40 NULL    NULL    utf8_unicode_ci NULL
```

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'key_buffer_size'

```
key_buffer_size 16777216
```

Comment: Have you tried incrementally removing bits of it to see at what point it speeds up? I'd try without the GROUP_CONCAT stuff and see what difference that makes, for example.

Comment: My first guess will be the `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`. What I think this does is Per tag_id and per tag it will scan the entire table   to make sure you only have the distinct records. My guess is that there is your bottle neck.

Comment: If I completely comment out the two GROUP_CONCAT but keep the joins, so the query looks like `SELECT postdata.data_id as data_id FROM postdata ...` it stays as slow.

Comment: Check the size of the index of postdata table with SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM [database_name] WHERE Name='postdata'

Comment: And also your 'key_buffer_size' with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'key_buffer_size'

Comment: @jordeu updated question with results

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use an INNER JOIN after a LEFT JOIN.

Try this approach:

```
SELECT 
    postdata.data_id as data_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tag.tag_id)) as tag_ids, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tag.tag) ORDER BY tag.tag ASC) as tags
FROM postdata
    LEFT JOIN tag_data as tag_data
      ON postdata.data_id = tag_Data.data_id
    LEFT JOIN tag as tag
      ON tag_data.tag_id = tag.tag_id
GROUP BY postdata.data_id
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: It only sped it up by a second. but at leas the query is now clearer

Comment: here it is https://gist.github.com/a298a46a32b1c4c948e1
 it's weird it shows hook_data uses no index but the primary index is on data_id and tag_id

Comment: It seems ok, may be the problem is that your indexes don't fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is that your index don't fit in memory, this slow down MySQL.

Increase your 'key_buffer_size' for example to 160Mb:

```
SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = 167772160
```

If you are using InnoDB you also may need to increase 'innodb_buffer_size'.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do it as easily as that, my database is on RDS. Is there a way to check if that is the problem without trying?

Comment: If you have shell access you can check if mysqld is swaping with `ps`. Without shell access I don't know how to do.

Comment: Here a good article about it: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/21/troubleshooting-mysql-memory-usage/

Answer (score 0):

If as commented, the DISTINCT is being evil, you could remove the `DISTINCT` and make them unique like this:

```
$arr_tag_ids = array_unique(implode(',', $row->tag_ids));
$arr_tags = array_unique(implode(',', $row->tags));
```

Comment: unfortunately, the distinct doesn't seem to be the cause. check my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

From your EXPLAIN it looks like it's not using any INDEXes on your first join. This may be because you have both JOINs and then both ON conditions. I've not ever seen a JOIN formatted like that. Try changing that like this

```
SELECT 
    postdata.data_id as data_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tag.tag_id)) as tag_ids, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tag.tag) ORDER BY tag.tag ASC) as tags
FROM postdata
    LEFT JOIN tag_data as tag_data
      ON postdata.data_id = tag_Data.data_id
    LEFT JOIN tag as tag
      ON tag_data.tag_id = tag.tag_id
GROUP BY postdata.data_id
LIMIT 1000
```

Then re-run EXPLAIN and see if it makes a difference. Also do you definitely need a LEFT JOIN for the first JOIN? Changing that to an INNER JOIN might help if it's possible.

Comment: @chaft Ok, yes, good point. I have changed the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN which should get the query working again. Are your tables INDEXed on both PRMARY and FOREIGN keys? i.e. Does `tag_data` have an INDEX on `data_id` and `tag_id`?

Comment: yes, the primary index of tag_data is on both data_id and tag_id

Comment: @chaft Can you post the schema (including INDEXes) for all 3 tables?